# grpc uses wrong ip address

Tags: node.js, dns, ip, grpc

When starting my grpc server, I get an error saying 'No address added out of total 1 resolved' and 'server must be bound in order to start'. After comparing it with a working server, I realised that, while the working service uses 127.0.0.1 with the configured port as the ip address, the broken service tries to use 0.0.31.170 port 443. This incorrect address is passed from line 156 in the resolver-dns.js file (got this from running npm install @grpc/grpc-js). Does anyone know why this could happen? This is how my server is created in short:

```
server.bindAsync(process.env.GRPC_PORT, credentials, () => {
  server.start();
  console.log("gRPC server started at " + process.env.GRPC_PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your question fully.

see: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/node/basics/#starting-the-server

You need to:

- include some form of the host name|IP **and** the port (`host:port`) in `bindAsync`
- if you're not using TLS, you'll want `createInsecure` too

i.e.:

```js
server.bindAsync(
  `${process.env.GRPC_HOST}:${process.env.GRPC_PORT}`,
  grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), () => {
    server.start();
    ...
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. This one was hard to explain. It looks like the package couldn't always figure out what the name/ip is of the device it is running on. Adding a host name or ip address solved the problem.

Comment: No apology necessary; it was likely my issue. I'm pleased to read that it's working